# Javascript callback on close window confirm and cancel

Tags: javascript, callback

I need callback from closing window to do some stuff.
So if user try to close window show a popup dialog with two option confirm and Cancel.
If you click on each one return a callback to add background to a div.
If user canceled add red background and if confirmed add green background. 
Appreciate your help.

This is my code but **it's not Working**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
         e = e || window.event;


        if (e) {

            document.getElementById("div").backgroundColor = "#1ab2ef";

        }else{

            document.getElementById("div").backgroundColor = "#1ba97f";
        }

        return 'Are you sure?';

    };
```

Comment: Are you talking about if the user tries to close the actual browser window/tab?  The most you can do in that situation is get the browser to display it's own popup with some text you supply (although Firefox ignores it).  See the [`beforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)

Comment: Please show the code you have written.

Comment: @James Thorpe yes i'm talking about the current window or browser tab.